# Appium doesn’t see the UIALabel text that is displayed

Tags: ios, appium

I'm using Appium 1.3.1, iOS8, and java bindings 2.1.0. The app has a TTTAttributedLabel field. TTTAttributedLabel is an inheritor of UILabel (see https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel). The thing is that somehow I can't see this field in the Appium Inspector. I do see the text on the app on the emulator and I don't find the field with corresponding test in the Appium Inspector. 
I tried to assign an accessibility label to the field in the app and then access it, however it resulted in "element can't be found blabla..."
Could you please help?

Comment: As of iOS 7 `UILabel` also supports attributed strings so you might not need `TTTAttributedLabel `

Comment: @rckoenes, thanks, but, unfortunately it's not my call to make. Also I'm not sure if UILabel would be better in Appium-wise perspective

Comment: possible duplicate of [xCode UIAutomation can't interact with TTTAttributedLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843986/xcode-uiautomation-cant-interact-with-tttattributedlabel)