# Xcode UIAutomation can't interact with TTTAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, appium, tttattributedlabel

I'm trying to write automation scripts for my app and my problem is that Xcode UI Automation just can't see the elements of [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) class. Getting full elements tree shows no sign of those `TTTAttributedLabel` elements. I'm using Xcode 6.1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `TTTAttributedLabel` isn't an accessibility element. It works as custom container and provides accessibility for links/phones and other detected data.
To change this behaviour subclass `TTTAttributedLabel` and override methods of `UIAccessibilityElement` protocol.

E.g. return `YES` in `-(BOOL)isAccessibilityElement` method and `TTTAttributedLabel` will work as `UILabel`